# Question answer statistics

Tags: feature-request, statistics

Are there any statistics available correlating when a SO question is asked until when it receives an upvote or an answer.

I feel like if you ask a good question that's relevant to a large number of people and one that will usually gain a reasonable answer that it's answered in the first 8 hours or less when that question is posted.

I do understand that some questions are really really specific and really really useful to a certain group of developers so maybe those don't fall into that category.

It'd just be interesting to know the emergent behavior of questions/answers on SO, this is probably all rolled into "featured" questions etc.

Comment: Yes, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/best-time-to-ask-questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly analyze this using [the public data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).