# Hourly usage statistics

Tags: support, statistics, usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Time to Ask Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/best-time-to-ask-questions)

Can anyone tell what hours of the day are more active on SO sites? A 24-rows of data would be enough like the following one:

```
Interval         # of views in average
-----------      ---------------------------------
00.00-00.59      1243
01.00-01.59      1179
...
23.00-23.59      1453
```

Of course, some data (at least a few months) are needed to calculate the averages. Number of views can be replaced with number of logins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are the [excellent graphs by Greg Hewgill](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html).

Questions per hour:

[image: Questions per hour, peak is at 15 (UTC)]

Answers per hour:

[image: Answers per hour, peak is at 15 (UTC)]

The time zone is UTC.

Comment: Awesome ‼ ‼ ‼ ‼