# Some statistics please

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics

What is the average reputation of all stackoverflow.com users?

Throughout the history of SO, what time (UTC) of the day has been proved to be the time with the least activity:

- fewest new questions coming in
- fewest logged in users
- fewest posts (comments, answers, questions) in general

Comment: "fewest logged in users" -- it's not possible to determine this using any end-user tools we have available. Jeff or another dev could probably find this out.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily get these statistics using [OData](http://odata.stackexchange.com/).

Here, I've [compiled you a query for the average reputation per User](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/634/average-reputation-of-all-users). But I'm too lazy right now to write the other one.

Comment: Here's the peak time data: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/best-time-to-ask-questions/1314#1314