# What time are Stack Overflow hackers most active?

Tags: discussion, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best time to ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions)

I'm in China, and I found out that the view counts of my questions increase very slow in my working time (8–17:00, GMT+8), as if hackers were happy sleeping in bed. Can I see the time histogram of answerings? When are there most hackers online?