# What would make a question popular with high views?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, views

I was wondering what might be making my questions less attractive to users?

I get very low views most of the time. What should be done to increase a question's popularity?

Comment: It all depends on your topic/tags and also the quality of your question.

Comment: [How to get your questions answered? « Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/)

Comment: Ask about the [color of the bike shed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality)

Comment: @RobertHarvey A bike shed question will only get a lot of _answers_ (everybody has an opinion!) but not necessarily a lot of views

Comment: 4 answers so far and nobody has mentioned the obvious: For better or worse, getting linked on social news sites like Reddit or Hacker news can bring in tens of thousands of views. **However:** The question and/or answers need to be "good enough" or it'll just get ignored there as well. (Note how I've intentionally left "good enough" ambiguous.)

Comment: Reddit. Definantly Reddit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Users generally gets attracted to questions with maximum upvotes (*at least I do*). The tendency to check *what's so cool in this question* draws them into it. To make it attractive you have to do the following

- Make your question **interesting** and **challenging**
- Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
- Design your question such that it satisfies all Q & A standards as defined in [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)
- Adding a bounty would also help but don't sacrifice your reputation to get views on an easy question.

Comment: Very good tips.

Answer (score 13):

You can do several things:

- Post at a time [when people are online](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions) (because a question gets the most attention in the first few minutes)
- Make your question title interesting but informative
- Post with the proper tags. If appropriate with high viewed tags like [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [php](/questions/tagged/php), ...
- Put effort in your question, give enough detail to understand the problem with all code that is needed
- Too long questions scare off

  - Reduce the problem to the very core. Don't post long code segments
  - Avoid chatting
- Format your question propery

  - Put code in the code-block
  - Avoid horizontal scrolling in code blocks
- Stay put after posting!

  - Answer to comments.
  - The first minutes are the most important ones where you get the most attention. We like responsive askers.
- Improve your question and edit it. Doing that will push it in the *active questions* queue
- If you [have enough reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) then put a bounty on your question (after 2 days) to attract even more attention to it

Comment: i know I'm no good when it comes to choosing the title, but what about the time?

Comment: your question gets most attention the minutes after you post it. If many people are online that time then you will get more attention as if half the community sleeps at the time.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a [stellar](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/36/stellar-question) or [great](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question) question, (and this is really prioritizing things backwards) work with *currently popular* or very new (but popular!) software development tools.  Get stuck on something and think to ask the obvious question everybody will need an answer to eventually here on SO.  That's really it.

Answer (score 0):

- ***Interesting Title***
- Less congested text
- Well formatted text
- Regular use of **Bold** or *Italicized* text to highlight important areas
- *concise but comprehensive explanation*

The last one is quite conflicting statement, with it I want to say mention each and every related thing in a concise manner.

Comment: **DO NOT** just scatter bold or italic text through posts randomly--it makes posts look absolutely horrendous. When used in an appropriate, limited manner it can indeed be helpful. Also, I can't tell what "less conjusted text" is supposed to mean.

Comment: could be a misspelling of "congested". Big unbroken walls of text intimidate readers.

Comment: ***bold*** text **you** say? Well, **I** like the **idea** of that. No way *that* can **go wrong** at all.

Comment: how will anything after the first bullet cause views? a person decides to click and view the question based on title, tags, and perhaps the little preview text, which does not show the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It should be also noted that **some questions are more popular** than others **based on the topic** (tags) the question is related to.

- some tags are more popular then others, e.g. a question related to `Java` or `Android` gets more views than `Lisp`. You need to adjust your "Views" expectations accordingly.

Therefore, you should **compare the number of views** on your question **with similar questions in the same tag**.