# My post has 12 revisions with 10 edits I made and is still not changed to community wiki like the FAQ indicates

Tags: support, community-wiki

[This post of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149317/172011) has [**12 revisions**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/149317/revisions)* with **10 edits I made** and is still not changed to *community wiki* like [the FAQ indicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/172011) it should *after 10 edits by the original owner*. I think I have noticed that before on other posts.

So when does a post really automatically change into CW mode (so we can update the FAQ)?

<sub>* The last edit was 3 days ago</sub>

Comment: It still confusing. I clarified [with @Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172104/why-hasnt-this-question-become-a-community-wiki-after-10-edits-by-the-op#comment606336_172104) as he said it requires 11 revision *history entries*. And you have 11 revision history entry (excluding other guy's entry). But still not CW? How?

Comment: Also [this revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/173659/revisions) shows that the answer became CW on 11th history (i.e. after 10th edit) which only include OP edits.

Comment: I did tell you this [twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178350/145673) [before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179901/145673) :-)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Wow - you have a good memory! So it will be CW from the 11th edit on.

Comment: @MartinSmith - But as per [this revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/173659/revisions) the answer became CW after 10th edit.

Comment: @juergend - As far as I've seen it will happen on the next edit you make. I'm not sure why the text says "at least 10". Whether it can actually ever occur on the 10th edit.

Comment: @hims056 - Hmm. Good point. Clearly inconsistent.

Comment: It appears the threshold on Meta is bigger by 1 i.e. 11 edits by the OP will make a post CW. The [sample post revisions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/173659/revisions) where it was 10 edits was posted originally on Stack Overflow so probably taking the rules from there. Just a guess though, we better get official response here.

Comment: @Sha  [See this stackoverflow example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3183687/revisions)

Comment: @MartinSmith right, that's 11 edits. Hmm... so it's really inconsistent. Where's Nick when we need him?!

Comment: @juergend trying to reproduce it here, eh? ;)

Comment: Two thoughts: Quick edits in succession may be counted as a single edit for the purposes of wikification (I know this is true if you edit it within the first five minutes of posting it), and while question posts are subject to the "10 OP edits --> wiki" rule, I'm not certain that answers are.

Comment: @AdamDavis answers are subject to the "10 OP edits --> wiki rule", I've been bit by it

Comment: The person who originally created this rule cannot be a mathematician.:-) That's because no mathematician would ever have made this mistake. They clearly distinguish between `> 10` and `>=10`, so there are no cases of doubt. But whenever put in words, this may create ambiguities such as...see above.