# How to keep drawing attention?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, popularity

I am not familiar with the posting mechanism of SO. My questions are answered quickly most of the time.

Recently, I've ran into some questions that are not very well known to people, or are too much trouble to follow. Anyway, I haven't been answered for days on that one.

So I posted another question. Since I've kept working on the problem, it moved on a little, so the new question is a bit different, though it is highly related to the last one.

Then someone came up and asked me not to post duplicate questions. I fully understand his/her point, and I didn't mean to do it. Actually, I found SO is very helpful and I like it a lot. I would like to contribute to it.

My question is, given the massive amount of questions posted on SO everyday, and since we should not post duplicate questions, how to draw attention from potential respondents and not let the question sink?

Answer (score 3):

- You can put a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your question to draw attention to it
- You can edit your question in order to improve it. Then it will be put in the *[active questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active)* queue. When you do, there are a [few things to keep in mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149317/172011)

Answer (score 2):

If your new post was just an expansion of the original one then you should just edit that original post instead to add in the new details. That will 'bump' the post to the top of the active list.

Make sure it's tagged properly too so that people specifically watching particular tags related to your question would be more likely to see it.

Other than that you can create a '[Bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)' which will give more prominance to the question too, but costs you some reputation to do so as you have to offer some rep up as the bounty itself.

Answer (score 0):

- In the first instance you can edit your question to update it on your
  continued efforts to solve the problem yourself. This makes the
  question better and bumps the question in the active questions tab and front pages (aka the interesting tab). Don't do this just to bump the question though.
- If you run into a road block you can set a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to attract
  attention. Here you offer some of your own reputation to put your
  question into the featured tab. If someone answers your question you
  can award the bounty to the best answer. Note that the rep is gone
  regardless

However, if the question is truly related but different then try to make that clear in your question, you could even link back to the original question for context and explain what subtly different question you're asking

Comment: If I edit my question and save it, will its status be like a new post? I mean, back to the top? Thanks.

Comment: @NewLong Almost, it won't go back to the top of the newest tab, but will go back to the top of the active tab and be eligible to go on people’s front pages (aka the interesting tab)