# How can I improve view rate of questions I have asked?

Tags: discussion, views

I have asked about 3 questions in StackOverflow but my view rate is very low. Due to this I don't get answers quickly and sometimes no answes at all. I know a few methods to improve view rate of my questions like:

1. Offer bounty
2. Add more tags

Offering bounty is not feasible as of now as I have less reputation and I don't prefer adding unnecessary tags to annoy fellow programmers. Are there other methods to improve my situation?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149317/172011

Comment: Just editing the tags is not good enough - I am sure you can think of improvements and more information you can add to a question.

Comment: Use 4chan, reddit etc.?

Comment: @hjpotter92 will give it a try

Comment: Umm... may want to be careful posting your question on the rest of the interwebs... you can get a lot of attention and if you have a very good question then it'll end very well for you. If you don't have a very good, interesting, question then it's probably going to end very badly...