# My questions are not getting views

Tags: discussion, support, questions

There are a lot of questions here that are basically "why no one answer my questions?"

This is a bit different. I have several question unanswered, but I realize that also those questions have like 13 or 14 views, pretty sure MY VIEWS, the times I checked if someone has answer.

I asked my brother, who lives elsewhere, if he can see my questions and I sent him the direct links:  he says yes. So, for some reason, even if my questions are available, no ones see them. I do not think is something related with being bad questions of not following the rules, is more like the stack-overflow engine is not showing the questions to the public.

Why this could be happening?

Comment: Directing you to [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/282094) (which doesn't directly answer your question) provides lots of links in the **right column** leading to helpful answers. --- You need a great title, opening one or two sentences, great question or answer, and it needs to appeal to the most people - otherwise it's an obscurity that needs a following to keep it afloat, before it drifts away and is buried by bigger and better posts.

Comment: This question needs more details. On what site did you posted your questions that are having low views? When did you posted your questions? Are your questions using the correct tags? Are those tags popular? Are your questions answerable? Are your questions interesting?

Comment: @Rubén the question is fine IMO, it's a general discussion about questions with low amount of views.

Comment: Besides following the recommendations given in the comments above, you can (once you have more rep) put a bounty on the question to attract more views.

Comment: @Shadow. So far the question looks to me to be about the posts of one specific user. It will be great if the question be improved  or if we could add links to related posts... How about this one [What would make a question popular with high views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149316/289691)?

Comment: I was more concerned that there was some unknown setting that was preventing my questions from being exposed, but apparently this is not the case. Feel free to close the question if you don't find it helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Overflow gets *a lot* of questions.  Really, a ***lot***.  [Almost 16,000 in the last 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A1d..&searchOn=1), in fact.

That's a lot of questions to be shown to all the people browsing the homepage and question lists.  Showing each of 16,000 questions to 13 or 14 people every single day is pretty impressive: that's actually quite a lot of question views total.  But it means that each individual question won't get a lot of attention by default.

Your best bet is to give your question a good, clear title that will attract the attention of someone looking at a sea of many, many questions and think "I bet I can answer that" and click it.  And if that doesn't happen, that clear title will help other people find it later via search if they have the same question.  And who knows: maybe those people later will upvote or answer it.  A number of my posts have collected views and points slowly over time.