# When is the ideal time to hold a chat room event to accommodate the most users, in particular users with close vote privileges?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump, data-analysis, community-data

I wanted to run [a weekly, 1-hour event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208634/so-close-vote-reviewers-next-meetup-on-monday-nov-25th), and initially set the time, somewhat haphazardly, to my lunch hour, 9:00pm UTC (as I expected to be alone in participation at first anyway).

However, several users indicated interest, and one user expressed not being able to participate because 9:00pm UTC meant 2:30am IST (India Standard Time; and I imagine we have a lot of SO users there).

**When is the ideal time to hold a 1-hour chat room event, to accommodate the most SO users?**

Of course, this depends on the type(s) of users one wishes to attract. For example, for my event, I'd be ecstatic to learn

- which hour on a typical weekday has the most activity from users with >3k rep, or
- which hour on a typical weekday has the most moderation activity,

as these would correlate best to the type(s) of users I wish to attract.

<sup>* However one defines "activity"—whether "votes cast per hour" or "pages visited per hour," I have a feeling the results of most definitions would correlate well enough to determine an hour that's most likely to work well.</sup>

I might attempt to write some Stack Exchange Data Explorer queries, but besides that my T-SQL isn't too great, I'm under the impression that these kinds of entire-site-wide/entire-user-wide queries are likely to time out. Perhaps though there'll be ways to restrict the queries enough to produce meaningful results.

Comment: [what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/)

Comment: @juergend - Thanks! That definitely helps. Though, the data's from 2009, Stack Overflow's first year. It'd be nice to see some updated data. Also, can we keep this question open at least until I get a chance to write and try some SEDE queries? Again, my knowledge of SQL is practically non-existent, so I'm going to be a little slow.

Comment: You might not want to hold your event at the time of the _most_ activity, as that is very likely to be the time that most people are actively trying to solve their immediate programming problems, i.e. working!

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I agree! That's one of the reasons I was skeptical about using _posts_ as a metric—I think it might work better to measure strictly _moderation activity_, _i.e._ the time when people are moderating queues and probably _not_ working very hard :-) I'm about to answer my own question with a query based on measuring suggested edit approvals and rejections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

**1:30pm UTC to 2:30pm UTC** might be the ideal time to hold a chat room event centered around moderation activity. (See the conclusion for a more qualified answer.)

---

## Background

To make the event widely to *users who review the close votes queue*, an ideal solution might have come from being able to query for data on close vote reviews. However, that data isn't yet available, though possibly underway (see [@Emracool's request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208801/please-make-close-vote-review-data-public) and [@Shog9's proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208806/please-add-close-flags-duplicate-links-and-review-data-to-the-public-data-dump)). Data on close and reopen votes seemed a promising proxy, but I found not only that full timestamps weren't available on the `Votes` table, but also that this data [stopped being available after June 25th, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208727/why-are-there-no-close-or-reopen-votes-in-the-data-explorer-following-june-25th) (due to internal refactoring).

So, what to use as a metric on activity?

@juergend, @rene, and @Dukeling all proposed some nice answers—measuring activity based on *posts*. @Dukeling also grouped his results by distinct users, which I thought was an insightful addition, since I'm looking to maximize exposure to active *users*, not just the *busiest* active users. I wasn't convinced though, about basing the metric on posts. Like @Dukeling commented himself, for example, higher rep users probably don't ask as many questions; and personally, while I agreed that answers and comments were good indicators of *activity*, I wasn't sure they'd correlate as well to *moderation activity*.

## Suggested Edits

**What about suggested edits (approvals and rejections)?** After all, the suggested edits queue is the most popular of the queues (next to the close votes one), and it's strictly a moderation activity. Here's a plot of suggested edits approvals and rejections in 10-minute buckets:

```
SELECT
  Time,
  COUNT(*) Activity
FROM
(
  SELECT
    UserId,
    DATEADD(mi, DATEPART(hh, v.CreationDate)*60
      + DATEPART(mi, v.CreationDate)/30*30, 0) AS Time
  FROM SuggestedEditVotes v
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.Id = v.UserId
  WHERE Users.Reputation >= 3000
) X
GROUP BY Time
ORDER BY Time
```

***Suggested edits: approvals and rejections by >3k rep users per 30-minute window:***

[image]

Interesting! Using suggested edits activity as a proxy for moderation activity, **it appears the busiest window of time for moderation is between approximately 9:00am UTC and 2:00pm UTC!**

At least two further adjustments can be made.

First, while doing some [related research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208827/what-is-the-distinction-between-votes-with-votetypeid-16-approveeditsuggestio), I noticed a pattern: not only are there distinct slumps in moderation activity over the weekends, but hour-by-hour shapes on the weekend look different, too:

```
SELECT TOP 30
  CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) AS Date,
  MAX(Count(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(CreationDate AS DATE)) as Activity
FROM SuggestedEditVotes
GROUP BY CAST(CreationDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

***Suggested edits: approvals and rejections per day:***

[image]

*Code omitted due to length. See query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149977#graph).*

***Suggested edits: approvals and rejections by >3k rep users per 30-minute window:***

[image]

So, first, let's filter out the weekend data, since I only plan to run my event on weekdays:

***Suggested edits: approvals and rejections by >3k rep users per 30-minute window (weekdays):***

[image]

Second, as @Dukeling first demonstrated, let's count distinct *users*, rather than distinct *actions*:

***Distinct >3k rep users approving and rejecting suggested edits per 30-minute window (weekdays):***

[image]

The queries are available [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150036/suggested-edits-approvals-and-rejections-by-3k-rep-users-per-30-minute-window-w#graph) and [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150001/distinct-3k-rep-users-approving-and-rejecting-suggested-edits-per-30-minute-wind#graph), respectively.

## Conclusion

Analyzing only weekdays and the actions of users with >3k rep, it appears that

- 11:30 UTC to 12:30 UTC sees the greatest number of suggested edits approvals/rejections.
- 13:30 UTC to 14:30 UTC sees the greatest number of *users* approving/rejecting suggested edits.

Using suggested edits approvals and rejections as a proxy for moderation activity, these times seem ideal for holding a chat room event centered around moderation activity.

Comment: Are you sure that "Suggested Edits" is a good proxy for moderator activity? I notice the Suggested Edit queue is often empty; so you may be measuring low-quality post volume or edit volume more than moderator volume... You may simply be measuring the time when the highest number of ESL speakers ask questions.

Comment: @Flimzy - I'm not sure—there may be _no_ good estimators until Stack Exchange releases data on close votes reviews. However, my line of thinking was that users moderating the suggested edit queue were at least _moderating_, _i.e._ they were all visiting the reviews page (where the close votes reviews are visible), and thus suggested edits may serve as a better proxy than _posts_ (questions, answers, and comments). That said, though the _creation_ of a suggested edit may be indicative of a low-quality post, the _votes_ (approvals and rejections) are made solely through the review queue.

Comment: I understand your line of reasoning; I just think it breaks down due to the relatively low volume of edits relative to the number of available moderators. I rarely if ever see more than maybe 25 suggested edits in queue, and quite often I see 0.

Comment: @Flimzy - You definitely have a point. Alas, I don't know at this time—I suppose we'll know when we get to query data on close votes reviews. For now, I need _some_ metric, and for some reason I trust one based on suggested edits more than one based on questions, answers, and comments. I appreciate your skepticism and will follow up if/when I think of a way to test your thoughts.

Comment: Good luck with your chat event :)

Answer (score 6):

[Here's a query that counts the number of 3k+ users active on any given hour (ignoring the day) since '2013-10-01'](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149827).

[Here's the same query, but distinguishing activity based on the day](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149833).

These queries are largely unoptimized - they're just the first way of doing it that came to mind. There could be plenty of ways of getting more in-depth results - feel free to extend it appropriately, I just provided the basic query.

The results show that the ideal time is largely focussed around 15:00 - 16:00 (UTC apparently), but the deviation in the intervals around that interval is not too great.

By just changing the `ORDER BY`, [I get a nice little graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149834#graph):

[image]

(x-axis is hour, y-axis is number of users)

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! Already +1'ed yesterday. I'm still trying to cook up a query that might be more precise to my aims (_e.g._ counting moderation activity of some sort, rather than posts and comments), and I'll likely post my results later today.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149792/number-of-posts-distributed-over-day-of-week-and-hour) only looking at new questions

```
select top 1 * 
from 
(
select datename(dw,creationdate) as dayofweek
, datepART(hh,creationdate) as hour
, count(*) as numofposts
from posts
where id > 15000000 -- limit due to timeouts
and posttypeid = 1 -- only questions
-- and creationdate > '2013-10-01' -- last month rougly
group by   datename(dw, creationdate)
, datepart(hh, creationdate)
) as t
order by 3 desc
```

the outcome is:
'Thursday' from 15:00 to 15:59 (I assume that is GMT/UTC...)

Comment: I think using both `id > 15000000` and `creationdate > '2013-10-01'` is redundant. Don't posts with an ID > some post's ID, also have a creationdate later than that post?

Comment: I think it is rather UTC time.

Comment: @juergend - Is there a difference between GMT and UTC?

Comment: No there is not. Just looked it up. Interesting :)

Comment: @Dukeling You're right but I kept getting timeouts and I wondered if the creationdate maybe lacked an index so I added the id hoping the query plan would choose an index, which it did...

Comment: `creationdate` doesn't have an index, but `id` does have one (i.e. you can just query on `id`).

Comment: Some concerns: (1) Why only questions? (or is it just performance concerns?) Some high-rep users post very few questions. (2) You're not taking user ID into account - users who post a lot of content can taint the results.

Comment: Only questions was indeed due to performance (I got timeouts). I saw juergen d his query (he deleted his answer though) also take votes into account which is also a good idea. I was trying another query to indeed have a unique visitors count per day but that didn't fly quick enough but I see you managed that nicely!

Comment: Thanks for this code, @rene! It was a very useful starting point—I'm now trying to build some queries that are more specific to moderation activities.