# Why are there no close or reopen votes in the data explorer following June 25th, 2013?

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer

I ran this query

```
select distinct CreationDate
from votes
where (VoteTypeId = 6 OR VoteTypeId = 7)
order by CreationDate desc
```

and got

[image]

(That's showing the top of the list.) What's going on? I know SEDE data isn't updated in real-time, but I remember reading somewhere that a dump was uploaded at least monthly. There are 1,269,633 close and reopen votes in the `Votes` table, but none after June 25th, 2013:

```
select count(*)
from votes
where (VoteTypeId = 6 OR VoteTypeId = 7) AND CreationDate > DateAdd(dd, -151, GetDate())
```

Removing the `VoteTypeId` constraints, it's clear there *are* votes for other types.

---

I wrote [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149968/see-the-creationdate-of-the-most-recent-vote-record-per-votetypeid) that displays the `CreationDate` of the most recent `Vote` record per `VoteTypeId`:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a side-effect of the recent close vote changes. Specifically, there was a major refactoring of how flags and close votes work behind the scenes that happened along with the introduction of custom off-topic close reasons.

Close votes and flags are now stored in a different table, and unfortunately those database changes haven't made it into SEDE yet. I'll see what we can do about that.

(As a side note, the review data isn't available through SEDE yet either. We should probably include that, too.)