# Please make close vote review data public

Tags: feature-request, review, data-analysis, community-data

I'd like to play around with the close vote review data to do some basic analysis. Can the review data from the close vote queue please be made public?

User IDs should be included in the data dump, as they are available anyway. The reason I'd like username data to be there is because I want to look at the trend in number of reviews per reviewer over time (and a couple other things); doing so would be impossible without username data.

Comment: The username data is public anyway... I don't see that it would be a problem to add it in.

Comment: The only time it's not public is for close votes that don't result in an action.  If only four people vote, their names are not released.  Only once the question is closed does that information become public.  At that point I don't think there's a good reason to withhold that from the data dump.

Comment: I would argue that the user IDs *should* be exposed. There is no anonymity in review.

Comment: Fair points, all. I'll change the proposal.

Comment: @AnnaLear indicated it's possible, in [a recent answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208727/why-are-there-no-close-or-reopen-votes-in-the-data-explorer-following-june-25th/208728#208728).

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I think it should stay open, actually. `@AnnaLear was answering as an aside on an unrelated question, _i.e._ users searching for info on close vote _review_ data wouldn't necessarily click on a question about missing close _votes_ data to expect their answer. Maybe we'll get more details in this thread too.

Comment: @acheong87 agreed, which is why I didn't actually vote to close.

Comment: Well, what I _meant_ was available for _download_, like a data dump, but I suppose DE works as well.

Comment: @Emracool I missed "data dump" in your question for some reason.  But I suspect the reason they aren't there is the same as they aren't in DE.

Comment: You're thinking too small, I think. Let's get it *all*: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208806/please-add-close-flags-duplicate-links-and-review-data-to-the-public-data-dump