# Cannot post question due to low reputation

Tags: discussion, support

I am attempting to ask a question over in Math.stackexchange in which I need to include a rather long formula. I am using the method specified in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-post).

Unfortunately due to 'low reputation' as a new user, I am not allowed to post the formula. I understand that this is done as a spam prevention measure, but it makes it rather difficult to seek help on stackexchange, particularly for someone who doesn't yet have the expertise to provide genuinely insightful answers to other questions in order to gain reputation. Is there any chance that readers of this query would be kind enough to upvote this post so that I could post my question on Math.stackexchange?

For anyone who is curious, [here](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B114800%7D%20%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bs%3Ct%7D%20%5CBigg%5B%20%5CBig%28%20-%5Cprod%5Climits_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7B15%7D%20%5Clambda_%7Bi%2Cj%2Cs%7D%5E%7Bw_j%7D%20%5CBig%29%20%20%20%5CBig%28n_%7Bi%2Cs%7D%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7B15%7D%20w_j%20log%28%5Clambda_%7Bi%2Cj%2Cs%7D%29%20%5CBig%29%20-%20%5CBig%28%20log%28n_%7Bi%2Cs%7D%21%29%20%5CBig%29%20%5CBigg%5D) is a link to the formula in question. I am aware I could simply post a link in math.stackexchange but I would much prefer to have the formula within the question itself so that stackexchangers can see it in the context of my query, which refers to terms within the equation.

Comment: You should ask questions like this at the respective site's meta: meta.math.stackexchange.com.  Usually, if you add the link to your question and a tiny note below that you don't have the rep to show it, someone will edit it in for you.

Comment: @Won't OP lacks 5 rep required to participate in [meta-tag:per-site-meta] and they don't have questions at main site which would allow them to use recently implemented [feature to ask about their own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/165773)

Comment: In general, @Won't has good advice there, but right move to post here since you didn't have the rep for meta.math.

Comment: That's terrrrible!

Comment: I had posted [an answer regarding increasing one's reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281460/333455); it's unlikely to help immediately, but might help you (or any future reader) achieve minimal points for various privileges somewhat sooner.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using the Google Chart API as the answer to your linked thread specifies, you're actually using images. New users are indeed not allowed to post (m)any images to prevent spam.

Fortunately, there's another way. Mathematics has MathJax enabled, which is a LaTeX-based math formatting language. You can use it by surrounding a math formula with `$` signs (or `$$` for a formula on its own line). These are all valid formulae:

```
$$ 1 + 2 $$
$$ x + y $$
$$ x = \frac{y}{z} $$
```

They become the following when rendered:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had initially looked for a solution like this and read that stackexchange didn't support LaTex formatting. Good to hear that math.stackexchange does!

Comment: @AlexanderChristensen It varies site-to-site. Some sites do, some don't - generally, the science or math-focused sites tend to have it enabled.

Comment: Here's a complete list of sites that support MathJax: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/329351