# What affects the visibility of a question?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, visibility

I have been a regular user of the UX Stack Exchange website for about 2 years and I have always wondered about what brings more views to the question. And not just within the aforementioned site or across the internal network but outside as well.

I failed to notice any patterns as such but I did see strangely high traffic on certain questions while sometimes noticed no traffic at all for questions with great value and popular tags. Also, the activity on the question also seems to affect it differently. It makes sense for a question with 10 or 20+ answers to have a high view count. But questions with 1 or 2 answers also tend to have high traffic.

This made me curious as to what makes a question on this network "hot". Do certain tags improve the visibility? Does posting at a certain time matter? Or is it just completely at the mercy of the internet gods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This made me curious as to what makes a question on this network "hot".

There is a certain [score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/295232) for that. Note that the question and answer(s) first must have some upvotes from the site itself before the question can become a Hot *Network* Question. After the hot network period ends, it's usually a matter of how often people Google for the problem. Somehow [this Puzzling question of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52507/11110) consistently gets about a hundred views a week.

> Do certain tags improve the visibility?

That depends on the site. On large sites, definitely; on Stack Overflow, most people watch one or more tags and usually completely ignore the other questions. On smaller sites, you have more people who read almost everything, and an attractive (possibly even 'clickbaity') title is more important than tags.

> Does posting at a certain time matter?

<s>I doubt it. I've conducted [some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329143/4751173) a while ago about posting times and concluded they had no influence (the reduced traffic is compensated by the reduced number of questions vying for that traffic). But it could be that posting during the weekend or outside European and American office hours will make it hard for a question to compete with the ones already in the list.</s>

**Yes, it does; it's best to post them on Sunday.** [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1385059/hot-questions-by-posting-day-of-week-time-network-wide#graph) is a SEDE query which lists the % of questions which become a Hot Network Question. The x-axis starts at Sunday 0:00 UTC, and you see that after 30 hours, when the workweek begins, the percentage drops significantly, only rising again when it's Saturday.

[image]

I get similar results when excluding Stack Overflow (which makes up for most of the questions in the network), but even when limiting to a single site, e.g. Worldbuilding (using 8-hour buckets for clarity), [the effect is clearly visible](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/1385063/hot-questions-by-posting-day-of-week-time?hoursToGroup=8#graph):

[image]

Why would this be the case? There is less voting during the weekend, and I suspect 'hotness scores' are lower (I should be able to check that, since I [regularly scrape the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315017/295232)) so it's easier for new questions to enter the list.

Comment: It is quite interesting. I am pretty much unaware of how SEO works (shame on me), but do the internal tags add weight to a search engine's capability of showing a certain questions in their search results?

Answer (score 3):

> I failed to notice any patterns as such but I did see strangely high traffic on certain questions while sometimes noticed no traffic at all for questions with great value and popular tags

Quite honestly? Sheer dumb luck. With 25K (or being a mod) you can actually find site analytics on your site at `tools/site-analytics/traffic-sources/`

On SU - which is one of the bigger/older sites, you'd find something interesting

[image]

*Most* of our traffic is off of search, and very little is organic to site users. You're going to get *answers* and *votes* off that 4%. You're going to get views off the other 95%. YMMV depending on the site.

Optimising individual posts for search engine friendliness is a fool's quest so... well, its mostly luck ;)