# Are there times that questions are more or less likely to get closed as off-topic before they can get answers?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic, time

I was wondering whether the time that a question is posted has an effect on whether the question is likely to get closed as off-topic. I noticed that some questions that look like they fit the description in a site for being off topic stay open long enough to get multiple answers while others, get closed as off-topic before they can get any answers.

Accounting for the layout of a question, are there times of day, week, month, or year that questions are more likely to get closed as off-topic before they can receive any answers?

Comment: Very much related, most likely dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions. (Doesn't mention closed as off topic or not, so not hammering)

Comment: Depends a lot on the site, I suppose. Some sites have stronger curation.

Comment: This is almost certainly answerable with SEDE at least in _theory_, but it's going to have the problem that you'll only be able to grab ~10 days or so of data due to the [Roomba](/help/roomba) deleting what I expect to be the vast majority of unanswered closed questions from earlier.

Comment: There are certainly daily and weekly activity patterns, but that would in first order only make everything a bit faster or slower, not shift the weights to more/less curation. I wouldn't expect a big effect. Please note that always some questions slip through and remain open even though they should get closed.

Comment: Reminds me of [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12033/100430).